# Coinbase API/SDK for converting USD to USDC without fees

Tags: fees, coinbase, payments, usdc, convert

I want to use some API/SDK of Coinbase in my dapp for **converting USD to USDC (buying USDC)  without fees** in Polygon network, **like on Coinbase web-site**. But that should be handled without creating a Coinbase wallet, just to convert USD to USDC to some blockchain address and back(I know converting from USDC to USD can be with fees depending on ‘net conversion’).

Is there some API or SDK that suits my request?
I was looking at Pay SDK of Coinbase, but I couldn’t find any info regarding to free-fees for that USD/USDC kind of conversion.

Really looking forward to answers. Thanks!